# iOS6 Twitter integration

Tags: cocoa-touch, twitter, ios-simulator, ios6

There seems to be a difference between the iPhone simulator and actual device when checking if Twitter is available.

I check if a Twitter account is setup by using this code: `[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];`

In the simulator there is a nice `UIAlertView` informing the user that there are no Twitter accounts setup and two buttons one for Settings and one for Cancel.

However when I run my app on my device it will not show the above `UIAlertView`. Why is that? And how can I catch what button is tapped in the above `UIAlertView` (since I did not instantiate it?)

This is what it looks like on the simulator:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To handle the result of the Twitter call, You can use this snippet :

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{
        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [twitterController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
        default:
        {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled.....");

        }
            break;
        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
        {
            NSLog(@"Posted....");
        }
            break;
    }};

    [twitterController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    ...
    ...
   }
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Removing this check makes everything work as expected if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{

Answer (score 0):

I also am having the same issue that the device doesn't display the UIAlert like the simulator does. Until Apple fixes it, this is what I'm doing (not as clean or nice as the simulator, and requires the user to manually go to the homescreen) Apple, please fix this!

Edit: the stock Apple apps show the UIAlert perfectly of course, example: sharing a photo from the photo app without having a Twitter/Facebook account will display the correct UIAlert.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
    {
        mySLComposerSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
        [mySLComposerSheet setInitialText:@"Check out the app:"];
        [mySLComposerSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
        [mySLComposerSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlofyourapp.com"]];
        [self presentViewController:mySLComposerSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You need to setup an account in the Settings app under Twitter to use this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [mySLComposerSheet setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled){[mySLComposerSheet dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
        else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone){[mySLComposerSheet dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}

    }];
```